# Magento add info to order product

Tags: php, magento

For a new function in magento i'm lookin for a solution. Per order row i need to add a delivery date (for example):

Product 1 -> 22 June 2013
Product 2 -> 23 June 2013

It doesn't need a connection with the delivery controller, but is it possible to add data to an order row? And when yes, can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new column for the table `sales_order_flat`. Use observer method  to listen for event `sales_order_save_before` and add the value inside the observer method via `$order->setData('your_new_column', $value)`

Comment: This also works for an order line (product) and not a complete order?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16428/

check this extension.

also check
[Saving extra data with an order in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370235/saving-extra-data-with-an-order-in-magento)  and 
[How to add custom field to order in Magento?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11737570/how-to-add-custom-field-to-order-in-magento)